# Replacing a Key's value in App.config file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to set a simple batch to search for a specific key in App.config file and than change its value.

for example, here is the Key from my file which contains a lot of other keys as well:

here is a snippet of my file:

```
<add key="ClientScriptVersion" value="281114"/>
<add key="Chat_SkipCheck" value="1"/>
<!--NextTag API TEST-->
<add key="NextTagToken" value="Agfghjj5JVy0XDG"/>
```

I would like the script to find this value by searching for the key "ClientScriptVersion" which is a unique key in my file , and than replace the value of it with another value, lets say - 291114

Can you help?
Tnx, Yan

Comment: A snippet of you file.....

Comment: hi @SachaDee , i added a snippet of my file in my post, Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excellent [REPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855) from @dbenham

Comment: Hi @SachaDee, first of all thank you very much for your reply.
I've tested your batch and it does replace the string, but for some  reason it also adding "ECHO is off." lines in my file and also remove "!--" from some of the remarks lines and by this making them active.
Do you have any idea what causing this?

Comment: Effectively i didn't saw It. You better use REPL.BAT.